# Does the tensor product operation distribute over the (external) direct sum?

Tags: linear-algebra, tensor-products, multilinear-algebra, direct-sum

It has been asked before if it holds that $B\otimes (C\oplus D)\cong (B\otimes C)\oplus (B\otimes D)$, for B,C,D all being real vector spaces.

Is it known if the analogous statement, $(B\otimes C)\oplus D\cong (B\oplus D)\otimes (C\oplus D)$, is true?

Are there any good counterexamples?  Are there specific conditions under which this is true?

Comment: Hint: What are the dimensions of $X\oplus Y$ and $X\otimes Y$?

Comment: If it is true, then it necessitates that two of the factors among B,C,D have dimension 0.  Damn.  This thwarts my purposes.  Back to the drawing board.